# Playing animation once when a condition is met

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an Android application with a custom keyboard. From the keyboard I'm recording the number of pressed keys in each session. When more than 40 keys are pressed, I would like to start an animation. When more than 80 keys are pressed I would like to start the animation again, and so on. One possibility would be:

```
if (keysCount == 40) {
   // Start animation
} else if (keysCount == 80) {
   // Start animation
}
```

Unfortunately, testing for equality does not work in my case because I check with a thread the key count every 500ms and if a user is typing fast I might miss the event. So another possibility is:

```
if (keysCount > 40) {
   // Start animation
} else if (keysCount > 80) {
   // Start animation
}
```

The problem is that in this the animation is not only played once but all the time.

How can I play the animation once and only once when the `keysCount` is bigger than a multiple of 40?

Comment: Use a (atomic) boolean value to indicate whether the animation has been played or not?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes that would work when I only want it to play for example for keysCount > 40 but I also want it for multiples of 40. If I set the boolean to true after animation is started when keysCount > 40, then the animation is no more played when keysCount > 80 and so on.

Comment: How about reseting the boolean back to false, and reset `keysCount` to 0, when the animation ends? This way you only have to check for `> 40`.

Comment: @Sweeper I could reset the boolean but I cannot reset the keysCount because also other stuff is depending on it.